# Deploying deep learning model in android app

Tags: android, deep-learning, project

I am in my final year and working on a final year project wherein we are developing an android app for a face mask and social distancing. My question is, is it possible to deploy two models in the android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally possible to deploy as many models you want to put on your android app.
You shall go through the official documents of framework(PyTorch, TF etc) to get exact steps.